# How i can get all my objects on my array with $elemMatch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I'm trying to just catch the teams with ligue:"UEFA EURO" , so i used elemMatch to catch it but the query get me only the first object with "UEFA EURO" of my array.

my function :

```
getRanking: (req, res) => {
    Sport.find(
      {},
      {clubs: { $elemMatch: { ligue: "UEFA EURO" } } },
     

      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.json(data);
          console.log(data)
        }
      }
      
    );


   
  },
```

I'm supposed to have around 20 teams on my new array but my console.log data get just the first one !

also my bdd on mongodb :

```
clubs: [
    {
      generalMeanWeekly: [],
      tabDB: [],
      _id: 60b64520f0f7f662624ed539,
      nomClub: 'Italie',
      classement: 20,
      dateMatch: 2018-09-21T22:00:00.000Z,
      dateMatchStop: 2018-09-24T22:00:00.000Z,
      classementDB: 20,
      logo: '/images/Italie.png',
      adversaire: '',
      sommeDB: 0,
      pays: 'UEFA EURO',
      ligue: 'UEFA EURO',
      moyenneRank: 100
    }
 {
      generalMeanWeekly: [],
      tabDB: [],
      _id: 60b64520f0f7f662624ed539,
      nomClub: 'France',
      classement: 20,
      dateMatch: 2018-09-21T22:00:00.000Z,
      dateMatchStop: 2018-09-24T22:00:00.000Z,
      classementDB: 20,
      logo: '/images/Italie.png',
      adversaire: '',
      sommeDB: 0,
      pays: 'UEFA EURO',
      ligue: 'UEFA EURO',
      moyenneRank: 100
    }
{
      generalMeanWeekly: [],
      tabDB: [],
      _id: 60b64520f0f7f662624ed539,
      nomClub: 'PSG',
      classement: 20,
      dateMatch: 2018-09-21T22:00:00.000Z,
      dateMatchStop: 2018-09-24T22:00:00.000Z,
      classementDB: 20,
      logo: '/images/Italie.png',
      adversaire: '',
      sommeDB: 0,
      pays: 'FRANCE',
      ligue: 'ligue 1',
      moyenneRank: 100
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: $elemMatch will returin only one matching document from array, try [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator starting from Mongodb 4.4 in find() projection.

Comment: @turivishal is right. Here's a working Mongoplayground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SkqvpX5F1JA).